# Plotting with subplots in a loop in one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe, and I want to plot each column but first sort the column, so I do the plot in a loop. I want to combine all the plots into one figure, but the result is an empty figure with 9 separate bar charts following it.

```
dfPlot=  df[['column 1','column 2',
                        'column 3','column 4','column 5','column 6',
                          'column 7','column 8','column 9']]
#fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3,figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8)) # optional
count=1
for i in dfPlot.columns:
    ds= dfPlot.sort_values(i, ascending=False)
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(3, 3,count) 
    #ds[i].plot(kind='bar')
    plt.bar(ds.index,ds[i])
    count= count+1


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As you are not providing your data, I think you can try this way** :

```
dfPlot = df[['column 1', 'column 2', 'column 3', 'column 4', 'column 5', 'column 6', 'column 7', 'column 8', 'column 9']]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
count = 1
for i in dfPlot.columns:
    ds = dfPlot.sort_values(i, ascending=False)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 3, count)
    ax.bar(ds.index, ds[i])
    count += 1
plt.show()
```